# When dragging cells down, how do I get it to fill with even references (A2, A4, A6)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to fill cells with even references (condition A) but Excel provides me with complete series fill (condition B) when I drag down formula.

Condition A:

```
$A$1+A2
$A$1+A4
$A$1+A6
$A$1+A8
```

Condition B:

```
$A$1+A2
$A$1+A3
$A$1+A4
$A$1+A5
```

How can I fill with even cell references?

Comment: What have you researched or attempted in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that, which will work regardless of where you place your column of formulas.  Say you start your formulas in cell C3.  C3 would contain:

```
=$A$1+A2
```

The next cell, C4, would contain:

```
=$A$1+INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()-ROW($C$3))*2)
```

Set the $C$3 reference to match the location of the first formula.  Then copy the formula down for as many as you need.  It uses the INDIRECT function to calculate the second addition term of the formula and convert it to a cell reference.  The calculation doubles the actual row difference.

Answer (score 1):

The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) belongs in the *volatile* category with others like `OFFSET`, `TODAY`, etc. In this context, *volatile* means that the formula(s) will recalculate for every calculation cycle that the workbook experiences, regardless of whether a changed value will affect the formula's outcome or not. Functions in the *volatile* category make little difference on smaller worksheets or even in larger worksheets if the calculation is simple and the number of formulas involving the function is limited. However, with enough formulas and dependent formulas on a large worksheet at some point calculation lag becomes annoying.

If the use of `INDIRECT` adversely affects the performance of your workbook, here is a non-volatile solution.

`=SUM(A$1, INDEX(A:A, ROW(1:1)*2))`

Put in any cell and fill down to achieve the equivalent of `=A1+A2`, `=A1+A4`, `=A1+A6`, etc.